# Create a subtitle for menu items in Silverstripe CMS?

Tags: php, css, content-management-system, silverstripe

Hi I'm using Silverstripe CMS on the "Simple" template. I'm wondering how to create subtitles for the menu items.

The current navigation template is like so:

```
<nav class="primary">
<span class="nav-open-button">²</span>
<ul>
    <% loop $Menu(2) %>
        <li class="$LinkingMode"><a href="$Link" title="$Title.XML">$MenuTitle.XML</a></li>
    <% end_loop %>
</ul>
```

I'm thinking i could somehow edit `$Menutitle.XML` but how? Also the sub title should be displayed directly under the Title but as the same button. The SubTitle would need to have a different css rule so that it could be smaller. I know that the CMS has an area for me to edit the page titles which become the menu titles, would it be easy to add a subtitle to the admin like that or is there some other easier way? I only need to make a few of them.

Answer (score 3):

easy thing to do:

add a field to the `$db` array of your `Page` class:

```
private static $db = array('SubTitle' => 'Varchar(255)');
```

then add this field in the `getCMSFields` method in the same file:

```
public function getCMSFields() {
  $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
  $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', TextField::create('SubTitle'));
  return $fields;
}
```

now you can use the variable `$SubTitle` in your template like so, for example:

```
<li class="$LinkingMode"><a href="$Link" title="$Title.XML">$MenuTitle.XML - $SubTitle</a></li>
```

in case all of this sounds too complex, you should really run through the silverstripe tutorials first, see http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/tutorials/

Comment: It's going to be about a week before I can try to impliment this. Thank you guys. Looks helpful :)